# Как сделать чтобы у кнопки была анимация при появлении

Tags: html, css

Есть кнопка, мне бы хотелось чтобы она при загрузке сайта (ну тоесть когда она появилась) у нее появилась анимация типо что она вправо едет. Как это сделать?

```
    <a><button class="button1">Главная</button></a>
```

```
.wrap {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.button1 {
    margin-left: 30px;
    min-width: 220px;
    min-height: 40px;
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
    letter-spacing: 1.3px;
    font-weight: 700;
    border-radius: 1000px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgb(49, 0, 255), rgb(229, 0, 255), rgb(0, 233, 255));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, rgb(49, 0, 255), rgb(229, 0, 255), rgb(0, 233, 255));
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgb(49, 0, 255), rgb(229, 0, 255), rgb(0, 233, 255));
    border: none;
}

.button1::before {
    content: '';
    border-radius: 1000px;
    min-width: calc(260px + 12px);
    min-height: calc(60px + 12px);
    border: 5px solid #FF1493;
    box-shadow: 0 0 90px #00FFFF;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.button1:hover, .button:focus {
    color: #313133;
    transform: translateY(-3px);
}

.button1:hover::before, button:focus::before {
    opacity: 1;
}

.button1:hover::after, button:focus::after {
    animation: none;
    display: none;
}

@keyframes ring {
    0% {
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надеюсь это вам поможет

```css
body{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .button1 {
    margin-left: 30px;
    min-width: 220px;
    min-height: 40px;
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
    letter-spacing: 1.3px;
    font-weight: 700;
    border-radius: 1000px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgb(49, 0, 255), rgb(229, 0, 255), rgb(0, 233, 255));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, rgb(49, 0, 255), rgb(229, 0, 255), rgb(0, 233, 255));
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgb(49, 0, 255), rgb(229, 0, 255), rgb(0, 233, 255));
    border: none;
    animation: poyavleniye 1s ease-out 1;
  }

  .button1::before {
    content: '';
    border-radius: 1000px;
    min-width: calc(260px + 12px);
    min-height: calc(60px + 12px);
    border: 5px solid #FF1493;
    box-shadow: 0 0 90px #00FFFF;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out 0s;
  }

  .button1:hover, .button:focus {
    color: #313133;
    transform: translateY(-3px);
  }

  .button1:hover::before, button:focus::before {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  .button1:hover::after, button:focus::after {
    animation: none;
    display: none;
  }

  @keyframes poyavleniye {
    0%,25%{
      transform: translateX(-120%);
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
```

```html
<a><button class="button1">Главная</button></a>
```